# Send raw XML using jersey client?

Tags: java, xml, jersey

```
String xmlString = "<a>test</a>
WebResource resource = Client.create().resource("http://somehost.com")
resource.put(ClientResponse.class, xmlString)
```

How can something like the above work? I am not getting content-type of application/xml header on the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You could do the following for a put:

```
WebResource resource = Client.create().resource("http://somehost.com");
ClientResponse response = resource.type("application/xml").put(ClientResponse.class, "<a>test</a>");
```

---

You could do the following for a get:

```
WebResource resource = Client.create().resource("http://somehost.com");
ClientResponse response = resource.accept("application/xml").get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Comment: I want to do a put of XML String to the URL. not GET.